# Android Studio Giraffe - Internal error occurred while analyzing this expression

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I recently updated my Android Studio to Giraffe and I'm getting following error with my current and fresh projects.

> Internal error occurred while analyzing this expression: IllegalStateException: Kotlin light classes should not be found by JavaPsiFacade, resolving: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

[image: Gradle error]

I have tried to invalidate caches, to rebuild the project, to change Gradle & Kotlin version, to uninstall & reinstall Kotlin plugin but nothing seems to work. Is that a known issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting %appdata%/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudio2022.3 folder and reinstalling Android Studio fixed the error.